# Can I make \includegraphics[draft] ignore the file on disk for speed up?

Tags: graphics, compiling, draft

I am compiling documents with hundreds, potentially thousands of images. `\includegraphics[draft]{foo}` is still rather slow - it seems to read the images on disk to figure out how big they shall be.

But when I pass both `width` and `height`, this should not be necessary. Can I make `\includegraphics[draft]` not look at the files on disk, somehow? This would allow me to run multiple passes without graphics, followed by a single run with graphics.

Comment: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`

Comment: I need to remember to check `graphics.pdf` (and not only `graphicx.pdf`) next time. Thanks, @DavidCarlisle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

Will do what you ask.